# SBT can't resolve dependency in build definition

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm making an SBT task that needs to make a multipart POST request to a certain server. I want to use Dispatch to make the request. I have the following in `build.sbt` at the top level of my project:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "net.databinder.dispatch" %% "dispatch-core" % "0.9.5"
)
```

The task definition is in `project/Build.scala`. I have

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import dispatch._

object SubmitBuild extends Build {
  ...
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
[error] /Users/ken/xxxxtools/project/Build.scala:3: not found: object dispatch
[error] import dispatch._
[error]        ^
```

If I remove `import dispatch._` then sbt will compile. I know I have Dispatch installed. Why can't SBT find it?

Comment: Try to put `build.sbt` with `libraryDependencies` line in `project` folder. Also, these [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#sbt-is-recursive) can help to understand project structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to make references in Build.scala to some dependency it has to be declared in build's project not in the "project project". Meaning that it should be `project/build.sbt`.

It turns out that `project/Build.scala` is also a SBT project in the same way your project is.

SBT authors give a very good explanation in [sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html).